# How to insert a delete icon to text input and implement deleting text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I create the following text input:

```
<input type="text" class="signup-input text-value" name="" placeholder="e.g. example@url.com">
```

I have to implement a delete function (with an "x" icon which is displayed in the end of the input).

Comment: Can you post your javascript code and show where the problem with it is?

Answer (score 5):

You could set the `type` to `search` :

```html
<input type="search" class="signup-input text-value" name="" placeholder="e.g. example@url.com">
```

`type="search"` will add a `x` button inside the input, that deletes the content when clicked.

fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/rnfp59jg/**

Support for `type="search"` by modern browsers, from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input :

```
Feature     Chrome  Firefox (Gecko) IE  Opera   Safari
type=search 5.0     4.0 (2.0)       10  11.01   (Yes)
```

Comment: I tried it.... but it's a problem because i'n using another code which create multi inputs (right after i enter an input)

Comment: @davidkonrad that's neat! :)

Comment: @saritrotshild, I dont quite understand.  How does those "multi inputs" conflict with the first input? Do you mean you actually replace the `<input>` with a `<textarea>`?

Answer (score 3):

A good cross browser option would be to:

---

Place your input in a div, and then you can position your 'x' absolutely.
That way you can control how your browser will render the 'X'.

I've also included a fading transition, as well as the event handler itself:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.ex').click(function() {
    $('.signup-input').val("");
  });
});
```

```css
.wrap input,
.wrap .ex {
  display: inline-block;
}
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 30px;
}
.ex {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 10%;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  transition: all 0.8s;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  text-align: center;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.wrap input:focus ~ .ex {
  opacity: 1;
}
.ex:hover {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: tomato;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <input type="text" id="this" class="signup-input text-value" name="" placeholder="e.g. example@url.com">
  <div class="ex">&times;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice it hides the `X` when leaving the input box. +1. I would have used  `&times;` - `×` instead.

Comment: @davidkonrad: updated. Although, personally, I prefer to generate my shapes using [tag:css-shapes]

Answer (score 1):

Like given below code you can use it. It works in all browser

**HTML:**

```
<span class="surround">
    <span class="tagsh"> Name </span>

</span>
```

**JQuery:**

```
var clearIcon ='<span id="icon_clear">X</span>';
$('<input type="input" class="textbox"/>'+clearIcon).appendTo('.surround')
    .keyup(
       function(e){
           var $dad = $($(this).parent());
           $(this).val().length>0?
               $('#icon_clear').fadeIn(300).click(function() {
                   $('.textbox').val('');}):
                   $('#icon_clear').fadeOut(300);
           if (e.keyCode in {13:"enter",32:"space"}){              
               var text = $(this).val(); 
               $('#icon_clear').remove();
               $dad.append($('<span class="tag"><span class="plus"></span><span class="minus"></span> '+text+'</span>'));
               $dad.append($(this).val("").hide().show("slow").focus());
               $dad.append(clearIcon);
           } ;});
```

**CSS:**

```
.textbox{
    width:70px;
    border:1px dotted #ccc;
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding-right:18px;
}

span#icon_clear{   
    display:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#38468F;
    position:relative;
    right:21px;

}
span#icon_clear:hover{
    color:#ccc;
}
```

Here JSFiddle link:  http://jsfiddle.net/ketan156/7PnKS/98/

Comment: Good solution, +1. But in my opinion more cool with `&times;` - `×`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="search-wrp"><input type="text" class="signup-input text-value" name="" placeholder="e.g. example@url.com"><span class="close">x</span></div>
```

---

```
input{
    border: 0px;
    width: 100px;
}
.search-wrp{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 120px;
}
.search-wrp span{
     color: blue;
     display: inline-block;
     margin-left: 5px;
     paddin: 3px;
     cursor: pointer;

}
```

JS Code

```
$(function(){
    $(".search-wrp .close").on("click",function(){
        $(".search-wrp input").val("");
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bbw99eq8/2/

Comment: Nice solution, +1. But in my opinion more cool with `&times;` - `×`.